# ionic error generating xcode project with ionic build ios

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

My ionic project was previously building - however I can no longer generate the xcode project.

when I do a `ionic build ios`  I get:

```
~/ionic-project/platforms/ios/ionic-project/Plugins/ionic-plugin-deploy/IonicDeploy.m:345:27: error: no visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'loadRequest:'
            [self.webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:components.URL] ];
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

There is a similar error mentioned in the [ionic forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-compiling-on-ios-mac-os-x-el-capitan/42588), but the 'solution' makes no sense.

I'm running OSX 10.10.5

node 4.2.6

ionic 1.7.14

xcode 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pull request waiting who fix this issue:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deploy/pull/50

cordova-ios@4.x has deprecated some features (see https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md)

I hope it helps. Bye !